# PowerShell monitoring external processes as they run

Tags: powershell

I have a script that runs an external process which creates some output (a file) and then I also capture console output to file (the log)

```
try 
{
  p4d -r $root -jc | out-file $output
}
```

I later check the log output, grab some info and the script carries on.

The problem is that the external process could (and has once) stalled and I need a way to check that on the fly to handle the error.

The best way I can think to do this is to monitor the file that the process creates for increasing size. Obviously this isn't without issue as it could potentially stall at any point and we don't know the resulting file size.

I will likely check the size of the last successful process and use that to set some limits.

My question is how do I achieve the whole check a process whilst it's running thing?

Comment: Why don't u pipe the result from `p4d` to a variable, then analyze the run and pipe it to the file?

Comment: The result of p4d is taking a couple of hours to complete, should have mentioned this sorry. So I wish to know earlier that something is potentially wrong if possible